# How to improve the solution in ALNS metaheuristic

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, vehicle-routing, metaheuristics

I am solving the **CVRP** with **Adaptive Large Neighborhood Search (ALNS)** .

I used the following construction operators: `GreedyInsertion` and `regretHeuristique`, and the following destruction operators: `relaxShawDeletion` , `RoutePortionOperator`, and `LongestDetourOperator`.

But the solutions I get are very far from the solutions that are in the literature.

Do you have an idea on how I can improve the solution? Are there any other operators that give better solutions?

Comment: Are you trying to implement the exact same algorithm as one from the literature? Here is a recent LNS algorithm for the CVRP, you might find some inspiration https://doi.org/10.1287/trsc.2019.0914

Answer (score 3):

We encourage you to look at the code of [jsprit](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit), the open-source Java vehicle routing library. The jsprit approach is based on a "ruin & recreate" heuristic, also known as Adaptive Large Neighborhood Search (ALNS). The operators can be found [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/tree/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/algorithm) in the folders "ruin" and "recreate" respectively.